# Ignore Invalid charcters during string comparison

Tags: java, string, java-8

I am trying to match two string in Java which have an invalid whitespace or a funny character in play. I have tried couple of things and have captured my attempts in the code however, below does not work i.e. tester complains unmatched.

```
package org.example;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String actual = "*** Transaction with whitespace character ****** for replacement ***";
        String expected = "*** Transaction with whitespace character ****** for replacement ***";

        actual = actual.replaceAll("\uFFFD", "");

        String re = "[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\u0001\\u0000-\\u0010\\uFFFF]";
        actual.replaceAll(re, "");

        String re1 = "[^\\x09\\x0A\\x0D\\x20-\\xD7FF\\xE000-\\xFFFD\\x10000-x10FFFF]";
        actual.replaceAll(re1, " ");

        actual.replaceAll("\u001E", "");
        //actual.replaceAll("\uFFFD", "\"");

        String re2 = "[^\u0009\r\n\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]";
        actual.replaceAll(re2, "");

        actual = translate(actual);

        if(actual.equals(expected))
            System.out.println("Matched !! ");
        else
            System.out.println("Unmatched !!!");


    }

    static String translate(String input)
    {

        // Creating array of string length
        char[] output = new char[input.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            char tch = input.charAt(i);
            if (tch == 65533) // char �
                tch = (char)233; // é
            else
                output[i] = input.charAt(i);
        }
        return Arrays.toString(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> `actual.replaceAll(re, "");`

This doesn't do anything whatsoever. `replaceAll` does not change the thing you call it on; it makes a new string with the replacement applied.

Try `actual = actual.replaceAll(re, "");` instead.

Answer (score 1):

From [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) one can read:

> The String class represents character strings. All string literals in
> Java programs, such as "abc", are implemented as instances of this
> class. **Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they
> are created.** String buffers support mutable strings. Because String
> objects are immutable they can be shared.

In Java **Strings are Immutable**, therefore any method that *"modifies a String"* is actually always creating a new String with the desired modification applied on it.

And the same applies to the method [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)). For curiosity if you look at the `replaceAll` implementation you can see the following:

```
   public String replaceAll(String replacement) {
        reset();
        boolean result = find();
        if (result) { <-- match found
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            do {
                appendReplacement(sb, replacement);
                result = find();
            } while (result);
            appendTail(sb);
            return sb.toString(); // <--- new string
        }
        return text.toString(); 
    }
```

when the match is found a new string will be returned at the end  "sb.toString();" resulting from:

> replacing each matching subsequence by the replacement string,
> substituting captured subsequences as needed

Therefore you need to change from

```
actual.replaceAll(re, "");
```

to

```
actual = actual.replaceAll(re, "");.
```

The code with the fixes:

```
package org.example;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String actual = "*** Transaction with whitespace character ****** for replacement ***";
        String expected = "*** Transaction with whitespace character ****** for replacement ***";

        actual = actual.replaceAll("\uFFFD", "");

        String re = "[^\\u0009\\u000A\\u000D\\u0020-\\uD7FF\\uE000-\\uFFFD\\u0001\\u0000-\\u0010\\uFFFF]";
        actual = actual.replaceAll(re, "");

        String re1 = "[^\\x09\\x0A\\x0D\\x20-\\xD7FF\\xE000-\\xFFFD\\x10000-x10FFFF]";
        actual = actual.replaceAll(re1, " ");

        actual = actual.replaceAll("\u001E", "");
        //actual.replaceAll("\uFFFD", "\"");

        String re2 = "[^\u0009\r\n\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\uD800\uDC00-\uDBFF\uDFFF]";
        actual = actual.replaceAll(re2, "");

        actual = translate(actual);

        if(actual.equals(expected))
            System.out.println("Matched !! ");
        else
            System.out.println("Unmatched !!!");


    }

    static String translate(String input)
    {
        // Creating array of string length
        char[] output = new char[input.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        {
            char tch = input.charAt(i);
            if (tch == 65533) // char �
                tch = (char)233; // é
            else
                output[i] = input.charAt(i);
        }
        return Arrays.toString(output);
    }
}
```